# ASP.NET Core 2.1: What technique should I use to post a model that have a property that is a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a model for a Store. This store can have a variable number of telephones and cellphones.

```
public class Store{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual List<Phone> Phones = new List<Phone>();
}
```

The Phone model

```
public class Phone {

public int Id {get; set;}
public String Number {get; set;}
}
```

In my blade template I want to be able to post a variable number of phones. The problem is that I don't have the slightest of how to achieve it. If it is not clear I want to post form that creates a store with the telephones.

Comment: I am thinking about creating  a string property on the Store model and use javascript to create json string. On the server a process the json string and create the telephones.

Comment: You can just bind it to a select for example.  Also if you want to bind it to your own set of inputs... you can just use array syntax for naming it in html like name="[@i].Phones" being i the index in a for loop in your razor view for example.

Comment: How do you do `post a variable number of phones`, do you use JavaScript? Do you need to create Phones or select existing Phones when  you are creating store?What is `blade template` ?Can you show your view code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do it:

My Model:

```
  public class Store
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }//notice it is a property NOT a field.
  }

  public class Phone 
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Number { get; set; }
  }
```

Now this is in my view:

```
    <form method="post">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="text" />
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Phones.Count; i++)
        {
            <input asp-for="Phones[i].Id" type="text" />
            <input asp-for="Phones[i].Number" type="text" />
        }
        <button type="submit">Submit Phones</button>
    </form>
```

Notice I am using the array syntax for binding the fields.

```
asp-for="Phones[i].Id"
```

Also notice I am using POST

My action in my controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Store model)
    {
      //do something here with your phones: model.Phones
      return View(model);
    }
```

I think you could also bind it from a query string or url parameters. But the most common way to do this is using post on a form submit.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use manually created forms, forms from a different framework or dynamically created using javascript the name of the Phone fields should be "name=Phones[1].Number" for example.

Same for the Id field of the Phone class. That way the model binder knows how to populate your property in the Action.

The number "[1]" is the index of the item in the collection.  They have to be sequential for the whole thing to work.

The index is ZERO based so the first element must be Phones[0].Number for example.